# Backbone cleaning up element events

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I'm very new to Backbone and am struggling to work out how to unbind element events when switching between views.

So far I have a router which loads and renders a view...

```
define([
    "underscore",
    "backbone"
], function (_, Backbone) {

    "use strict";

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

        "views": {},

        "routes": {
            "bugs": "listBugs",
            "*other": "showDashboard"
        },

        "listBugs": function () {
            var oRouter = this;

            require([
                "views/bugs/list"
            ], function (View) {
                oRouter.views.bugsList = new View();
                oRouter.views.bugsList.render();
            });
        },

        "showDashboard": function () {
            var oRouter = this;

            require([
                "views/dashboard"
            ], function (View) {
                oRouter.views.dashboard = new View();
                oRouter.views.dashboard.render();
            });
        }

    });

    return Router;

});
```

I'm playing about with events in the dashboard view...

```
/* views/dashboard */
define([
    "underscore",
    "backbone",
    "text!templates/dashboard.html"
], function (_, Backbone, sTemplate) {

    "use strict";

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        "el": "main",
        "template": _.template(sTemplate),

        "events": {
            "click p": "testFunc"
        },

        "render": function() {
            var sHtml;
            sHtml = this.template();
            this.$el.html(sHtml);
        },

        "testFunc": function () {
            console.log("!");
        }
    });

});
```

The problem is that if I click between / and /bugs a few times and then click on a p tag, multiple lines are written to the console (because the dashboard view is being created multiple times) and also if I click on a p tag within the bugs view a line is written to the console.

What's the best (and simplest) way of unbinding that click event when the user navigates away from the dashboard?

---

Here's the bugs view, nothing much to it...

```
/* views/bugs/list */
define([
    "underscore",
    "backbone",
    "text!templates/bugs/list.html"
], function (_, Backbone, sTemplate) {

    "use strict";

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        "el": "main",
        "template": _.template(sTemplate),

        "render": function() {
            var sHtml;
            sHtml = this.template();
            this.$el.html(sHtml);
        }
    });

});
```

---

**My solution for if anyone is interested**

```
/* Router */
define([
    "underscore",
    "backbone"
], function (_, Backbone) {

    "use strict";

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

        "mainView": undefined,

        "routes": {
            "bugs": "listBugs",
            "*other": "showDashboard"
        },

        "renderView": function (oView) {
            if (typeof this.mainView !== "undefined") {
                this.mainView.close();
            }

            this.mainView = oView;
            this.mainView.render();

            $("main").html(this.mainView.el);
        },

        "listBugs": function () {
            var oRouter = this;

            require([
                "views/bugs/list"
            ], function (View) {
                var oView = new View();
                oRouter.renderView(oView);
            });
        },

        "showDashboard": function () {
            var oRouter = this;

            require([
                "views/dashboard"
            ], function (View) {
                var oView = new View();
                oRouter.renderView(oView);
            });
        }

    });

    return Router;

});
```

.

```
/* /views/dashboard */
define([
    "underscore",
    "backbone",
    "text!templates/dashboard.html"
], function (_, Backbone, sTemplate) {

    "use strict";

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        "tagName": "div",
        "template": _.template(sTemplate),

        "events": {
            "click p": "testFunc"
        },

        "render": function() {
            var sHtml;
            sHtml = this.template();
            this.$el.html(sHtml);
        },

        "testFunc": function () {
            console.log("!");
        }
    });

});
```

.

```
/* /views/bugs/list */
define([
    "underscore",
    "backbone",
    "text!templates/bugs/list.html"
], function (_, Backbone, sTemplate) {

    "use strict";

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        "tagName": "div",
        "template": _.template(sTemplate),

        "render": function() {
            var sHtml;
            sHtml = this.template();
            this.$el.html(sHtml);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason to create a new view every time the showDasboard method runs? Re-use your views and you will not have the problem of multiple views handling the same event:

```
"showDashboard": function () {
        var oRouter = this;

        require([
            "views/dashboard"
        ], function (View) {
            if(!oRouter.views.dashboard){
              oRouter.views.dashboard = new View();
            }
            if( oRouter.views.bugsList ){
              oRouter.views.bugsList.undelegateEvents();
            }
            oRouter.views.dashboard.render();
        });
    }
```

and of course:

```
 "listBugs": function () {
        var oRouter = this;

        require([
            "views/bugs/list"
        ], function (View) {
            if(!oRouter.views.bugsList){
              oRouter.views.dashboard = new View();
            }
            if( oRouter.views.dashboard ){
              oRouter.views.dashboard.undelegateEvents();
            }
            oRouter.views.bugsList = new View();
            oRouter.views.bugsList.render();
        });
    }
```

Then you will need to delegate them again when you re-render one of those views, in the render method of the view:

```
 this.delegateEvents();
```

Comment: No reason, I'm just very new to this :) That solves one problem

Comment: Can you show your bugs view to get rid of the second one, too? ;)

Comment: I've added it to the original post

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to check this repo:

https://github.com/RStankov/backbone-bind-to